# Finding "Solution" of the partial diffrential equation $z=px+qy+f(p,q)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Adding more to the title: $p=z_x,q=z_y$

My attempt:On applying charpits method,I get $dp/0 = dq/0 \implies $ $p=a,q=b$ so that

$$dz=a \, dx +b \, dy \implies z=ax+by+c$$

Putting for $z$ in the original equation $c=f(p,q)$ so that "complete integral to given pde is

$$z=ax+by+f(a,b) \tag A$$

In this way ,I get "complete integral" of the given pde.

FINDING SINGULAR SOLUTION OF THE GIVEN PDE:

Defining $g(x,y,z,a,b)=z-ax-by-f(a,b)$. It is as good as finding envelope of the two parameter integral surface $g=0$.

Which is given by eliminating $a,b $ from the system :$g=0.g_a=0.g_b=0$

FINDING GENERAL SOLUTION:This is where I got stuck. Please help. I'll appreciate any help.

PS: Well,I think the general solution will be obtained from $z=ax+by+f(a,b)$ by substituting $b=\phi(a)$ so final answer should be $z=ax+\phi(a)y+f(a,\phi(a))$, where $\phi$ is an arbitrary function. (Am I not right?)